# Solution of a differential equation of a RC filter (alternating voltage) and graph

Tags: filter, differential, alternator

I'm trying to solve the differential equation of a circuit on the capacitor for the first half-period (the capacitor is initially discharged):

[image]

So far, I have this differential equation:
$$RC_{1}\frac{dU_{C1}(t)}{dt} + U_{C1} = E_{1}$$
with E1 being $$E_{1} = U_{m}\sin(\omega t+\varphi)$$

According to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177182/solving-rc-filter-by-differential-equation), it seems that the solution of the differencial equation is:
$$U_{C1} = \frac{U_{m}\sin(\omega t + \varphi)}{1 + R^2C_{1}^2 \omega^2} - \frac{RC_{1}U_{m}\omega\cos(\omega t + \varphi)}{1 + R^2C_{1}^2\omega^2} + c_{1}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$

The problem is that I have to create a graph with this function (just a quick representation of the curve) but I have no idea what to do with this as it has a cosine, a sine and an exponential.
I asked some of my classmates and apparently I can treat the alternative voltage as being constant which I don't understand. The result of the differential equation would then be:
$$U_{C1} = E_{1}(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{RC1}})$$

Which one would be the right answer and how can I represent the curve (if the right result is the first one)?

Comment: You have both \$C\$ and \$c_1\$ in your formula. Is that an error?

Comment: @Andyaka no, c1 is the constant of the differential equation while C is the capacity of conductor.

Comment: It's just that the capacitor in your circuit has \$C_1\$ as its reference designator.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh yeah sorry, C is the same as C1 then.

Comment: You should fix your question in the appropriate way because comments may become deleted and are therefore an unreliable and clunky method for amending the question.

Comment: @periblepsis Well I have no information about the initial value of \$\varphi\$ so I just have to draw what it would look like (I don't have to be very accurate)

Comment: @Valrich I'll provide equation development, assuming the initial value of the capacitor is zero volts, and let you think about how that may look in the first half-cycle. You can plug them into a plotting program on the web, like Desmos for example, or use a simulator of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From KCL:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}+\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{R_1\,C_1}&=\frac{U_m\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)}{R_1\,C_1}
\\\\
\left[D+\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}\right]V_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{U_m}{R_1\,C_1}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)
\\\\
\left[D^2+\omega^2\vphantom{\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}}\right]\cdot\left[D+\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}\right]V_{_\text{C}}&=\left[D^2+\omega^2\vphantom{\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}}\right]\cdot\frac{U_m}{R_1\,C_1}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)
\\\\
\left[D^2+\omega^2\vphantom{\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}}\right]\cdot\left[D+\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}\right]V_{_\text{C}}&=0
\end{align*}$$

That last one is homogeneous. So the solution, with or without \$\varphi\$, is of the general form:

$$V_{_\text{C}}=A_0\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)+A_1\cdot\cos\left(\omega t\right)+A_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)$$

(The first term from \$\left[D+\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}\right]\$ and the second and third terms from \$\left[D^2+\omega^2\vphantom{\frac{1}{R_1\,C_1}}\right]\$.)

At \$t=0\$ then \$V_{_{\text{C}_\left(t=0\right)}}=0\:\text{V}\$, so it follows that \$A_0+A_1=0\$:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=A_0\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)-A_0\cdot\cos\left(\omega t\right)+A_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)
\\\\
&=A_0\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t\right)+\frac{A_2}{A_0}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

The derivative of the right-hand factor at \$t=0\$ must also be equal to zero:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-1}{\omega\, R_1\,C_1}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)+\sin\left(\omega t\right)+\frac{A_2}{A_0}\cdot\cos\left(\omega t\right)&=0
\end{align*}$$

So \$\frac{A_2}{A_0}=\frac{1}{\omega\, R_1\,C_1}\$. This is a good moment to define new terms and reduce scribbling. Call the driving to natural frequency ratio, \$\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}=\omega\, R_1\,C_1\$, and its inverse, the natural to driving frequency ratio, \$\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}=\frac1{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\$ Then \$\frac{A_2}{A_0}\$ is just the natural to driving frequency ratio, \$\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}\$.

Substituting:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=A_0\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t\right)+\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

As \$t\to\infty\$ the exp() function disappears, leaving only the other two terms. They are 90-degrees out of phase, so their magnitude is \$\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}}^2}\$.

Including \$A_0\$, this means the right-hand side's magnitude must be \$A_0\cdot\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}}^2}\$. But as this is an RC divider, this must be equal to the left-hand side's \$U_m\cdot\vert\frac{Z_{_\text{C}}}{R+Z_{_\text{C}}}\vert=U_m\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
U_m\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}}&=A_0\cdot\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}^2}}
\\\\
\therefore
\\\\
A_0&=\frac{U_m}{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}\,\cdot\,\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}^2}}}
\\\\
&=\frac{U_m}{\sqrt{2+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}}^2}}
\\\\
&=\frac{U_m\,\cdot \,\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}{\sqrt{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^4+2\,{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2+1}}
\\\\
&=U_m\,\cdot \,\frac{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}}{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}
\end{align*}$$

Thus, without \$\varphi\$ yet:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=U_m\,\cdot \,\frac{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}}{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t\right)+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

The sin() and cos() can be combined:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=U_m\,\cdot \,\frac{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}}{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)+\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\mho}}^2}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t-\arctan {\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\right)\right]
\\\\
&=\frac{U_m}{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}}\cdot\left[\frac{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}}{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)+\sin\left(\omega t-\arctan {\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

Noting \$\frac{{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}}{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}}=\sin\left(\arctan {\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\right)\$, adding in \$\varphi\$ isn't hard now:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{U_m}{\sqrt{1+{\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}^2}} \cdot \left[\sin\left(-\varphi+\arctan {\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-t}{R_1\,C_1}\right)+\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi-\arctan {\underset{^\cdot}{\Omega}}\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

That's the particular solution for \$t\ge 0\:\text{s}\$ with \$V_{_\text{C}}=0\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0 \:\text{s}\$. (That little \$c_1\$ in your linked solution is true, just unspecified, so it's not a completed particular solution.)